# How can I color a GUI.Button but also to change the button text size?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
var oldColor = GUI.backgroundColor;
GUI.backgroundColor = Color.red;
var searchButton = GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 55, 390, 30), "Search", guiStyle);
    if (searchButton)
        {
        }
```

This way it's changing the text size to be bigger but then not coloring it in red.
If I'm removing the guiStyle it will color the button in red but then the text size will be too small.

Comment: Unless you're doing editor scripting, stop using OnGui and use [the new UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're overwriting properties of the GUIStyle somehow. Get the default button `GUIStyle` from `GUI.skin.button`, and make the changes you want from that:

```
Color oldColor = GUI.backgroundColor;
GUI.backgroundColor = Color.red;

// make copy of default button style 
GUIStyle buttonStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.button);

// change font size
buttonStyle.fontSize = 18;

bool searchButton = GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 55, 390, 30), "Search", buttonStyle);
if (searchButton) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Working. And a sub question please: How do I change a TextField the size of the text inside when typing something ? objectsToSearch = GUI.TextField(new Rect(120, 90, 150, 70), objectsToSearch, 25, guiStyle); This change the size using the guiStyle but then it also make the Textfield Rect to be gone.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by make it to be gone but make sure `guiStyle.clipping` is set to  `TextClipping.Overflow`so that if it's too big, it can still display.